# MongoDb aggregate executing two times only to count my records

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregate

i've one question about find pageable and count my records in aggregate at same time, in my case i've this two aggregate:

This one is only to find records limited and pageables:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
             { $match : { ... }}, 
             { $project : { .. }}, 
             { $group : {... }},
             { $sort  : {... }},
             { $limit : 10}, { $skip : 10}])
```

And this other is only to count the amounts of records filtered and grouped whitout pageable:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
             { $match : { ... }}, 
             { $project : { .. }}, 
             { $group : {... }},
             { $count : "amount" }])
```

But i've a large database and this both aggregation is costly, so my question is:
**Could i get my records and count at the same time?**

Comment: You could, via `$facet`. But I don't think it's necessarily going to be any less costly/faster. I would almost expect the opposite. Also you probably don't need the `$project` in there (can't tell without seeing the actual definition though).

Comment: @user20042973 great suggestion, I got it using facet, I don't know if I used it in the best way, because in my facet I just projected the data received from the group and after $facet, i've projected them again but with the size operator too.

Comment: @user20042973 the "$project" is important to me, because in there i've some conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached results with `facet`, i've insert facets after the group:

```
{ $group : {... }},
{ $facet : {
  "data" : [{
      $project : { 
        _id : "$_id", 
        foo  : "$foo"
      }  
    }]}
},
{
  $project : {
      "amount" : { $size : "$data" },
      data : "$data"
  }},
{ 
  $unwind : {
       path: "$data"
 }},

{ $project : 
    {
        "amount" : 1,
        _id : "$data._id", 
         foo : "$data.foo"
     }
}
```

After this 4 operations i've the all datas with the amount of datas too.